# Calculate percentage between two tables with group by -SQL (Impala)

Tags: sql, impala

I'm working on Impala (Cloudera) and I have two tables, Customers and Arrangements. Customer table has the following columns:

```
customercrs | customertype| 
------------+-------------+
 1000       | NP          |  
 100000     | NP          |   
 100001     | NP          |  
 100002     | GROUP       |  
 100023     | GROUP       |
 100024     | INDIRECT    |
```

Arrangement table:

```
customercrs | arrangementid| 
------------+--------------+
 1000       | 11000000361  |  
 100000     | 11000000370  |  
 100000     | 11000000434  |
 100000     | 11000000426  |
 100001     | 11000000418  | 
 100001     | 11000000400  |
 100001     | 11000000396  |
 100001     | 11000000388  |
 100002     | 11000000591  |  
 100002     | 11000000582  |
 100023     | 11000000574  |
 100024     | 11000000566  |
 100024     | 11000000558  |
```

I want to calculate the percentage of arrangements per customertype. Something like:

```
customertype | percentage  |
-------------+-------------+
 NP          | 62%         |
 GROUP       | 23%         |
 INDIRECT    | 15%         |
```

I tried the following sql query, but it didn't work. Any idea?

```
select customertype, count(*)/(select count(*) from arrangements)
from customers as a, arrangements_sample as b
where a.customercrs = b.customercrs
group by a.customertype
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: and what is wrong with the query?

Comment: AnalysisException: Subqueries are not supported in the select list
This this the exception that I get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to join the subselect, I used max as group function, but min or avg would work too...

```
select customertype, count(*)/max(c.total)
from customers as a, arrangements_sample as b, (select count(*) as total from 
arrangements) as c
where a.customercrs = b.customercrs
group by a.customertype
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use window functions together with explicit `JOIN`, however, your solution seems to be fine (for other DBMS than Impala)

```
select customertype, 
       (count(*) * 100) / sum(count(*)) over () percentage
from customers as a
join arrangements_sample as b on a.customercrs = b.customercrs
group by a.customertype
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but it seems that is not working. I get only the counts for each category and not the percentage.

Comment: @VickyK true, I just forget to the the `SUM`. Can you try now?

Answer (score 0):

you need participation of each customertype in total count of arrangments. so try following query.

select main.customertype,cast((cast(main.participation as decimal(10,2))/main.total)*100 as decimal(10,2)) as participation
 from (select customertype,COUNT(1) as participation,(select COUNT(1) from arrangements) as total from Arrangements a
inner join customers b on b.customercrs = a.customercrs
group by b.customertype) as main